# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 AWS Amplify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm currently working on a full stack project and I'm stuck on the POST request to update my database.  I'm using MERN and it's deployed using AWS Amplify.  For some reason when I process the POST request using the local deployment everything works as expected, however when I attempt this using the AWS deployment I get the following error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()".  Below is the code in question and anything that mught steer me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

index.js(server)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();




const PortfolioModel = require("./models/Portfolio");
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://EEngvall:*******@cluster0.frqsy.mongodb.net/Test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
});

app.post('/insert', async (req, res) =>{
    const firstName = req.body.firstName
    const lastName = req.body.lastName
    const emailAddress = req.body.emailAddress


    const portfolio = new PortfolioModel({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, emailAddress: emailAddress})
    try {
        await portfolio.save();
        res.send("Data Inserted Successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

app.listen(process.env.POST || 3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is booming on port 3001")
});
```

contactMeInput.jsx(client)

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/contactMeStyles.css";
import Axios from "axios";

function ContactMeInput() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState("");
  const addToList = () => {
    console.log(firstName + " " + lastName + emailAddress);
    Axios.post("/insert", {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      emailAddress: emailAddress,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="contact-me-main">
      <h2>Send me a message!</h2>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input
          className="input-item"
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input
          className="input-item"
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Email Address:</label>
        <input
          className="input-item"
          type="emial"
          onChange={(event) => setEmailAddress(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={addToList}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactMeInput;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have any `<form>` tags in your app that might be wrapping the `ContactMeInput` component?

Comment: The only place the ContactMeInput component is used in in a route but its only wrapped in a <div> within that component.